# How to get rid of white space or improper loading in jquery mobile in android?

Tags: android, performance, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am getting a white space between which is caused in jquery mobile in between at end of content and start of footer. I have this issue in android 4.0.3 and how can get rid of this issue.Kindly help me in solving this issue.I have added screenshot to show how I get it in emulator.Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please next time try goggling this problem, it is most commonly asked problem here.

As you can see **data-role="content"** will not cover available free space. So you will need to do this using CSS or javascript.

### CSS solution:

```
.ui-content {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute !important;
    top : 40px !important; 
    right : 0;
    bottom : 40px !important; 
    left : 0 !important;    
}
```

### JavaScript solution:

```
function getRealContentHeight() {
    var header = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='header']:visible");
    var footer = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='footer']:visible");
    var content = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='content']:visible:visible");
    var viewport_height = $(window).height();

    var content_height = viewport_height - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight();
    if((content.outerHeight() - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight()) <= viewport_height) {
        content_height -= (content.outerHeight() - content.height());
    }
    return content_height;
}
```

Read more about it **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/solution-to-jquery-mobile-page-content-empty-space-height-problem/)**, with working examples.